# краткая запись условия в си и c#

Tags: c#, c, while

Переписываю код с Си на C#. Встретился цикл

```
// инициализация a и b

    while (a & b)
    {
     ...
    }
```

При такой записи в c# VS выводит

> неявное преобразование типа 'int' в 'bool' невозможно

Я понимаю, что в си там, скорее всего, просто единичный вектор должен быть, но вот как корректнее всего это переделать в с#?

Answer (score 4):

Если прямо в лоб переписывать, то будет:

```
while((a & b) != 0)
{

}
```

То бишь цикл не завершится, пока все биты не разойдуться в обоих переменных. А так без контекста сложно сказать, допустим внутри цикла просто присваивается a = 0.Тогда можно заменить на bool и убрать != 0.

Comment: Ну это да, просто я думал, можно как-то по-красивому.

Comment: Чтобы по красивому, нужно разбираться что внутри цикла

Comment: @Setplus: Чтобы получилось красиво, надо не переписывать один к одному, а использовать специфические для языка возможности. Например, тип `bool` или там LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуй. Ты запускаешь цыкл и указываешь что "A и B", а условия нет. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while

Comment: В том-то и дело, что в языке Си это корректная запись. В отличие от Си-шарп.

Answer (score 0):

В C# есть отдельный булевый тип, и неявно использовать остальные целочисленные типы нельзя. В Си напротив - нет булевого типа, и используются любые целочисленные тыпы. И самое главное, о чём нужно помнить - в Си является ложным (false) значением только 0, всё остальное - истина (true). При портировании Си-кода на C# нужно смотреть - если в условии нет проверки на равенство, а просто целочисленное выражение, то надо в C# код дописать "!=0" к нему.